# Parse & Rubymotion

Tags: parsing, sdk, rubymotion

I cannot get parse to work with rubymotion. I tried using the cocoapod and vendoring the project. I must be missing something trivial. The ideal scenario to me would be to use the pod as opposed to vendoring the project, but I'll use whichever I can manage to get working.

I use pods all the time, so I don't think my cocoapods setup is messing anything up. The runtime error I get with this setup occurs when I try and set my app id and client key with:

```
Parse.setApplicationId('xxx', clientKey:'yyy')
```

I get this guy:

```
app_delegate.rb:6:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': uninitialized constant AppDelegate::Parse (NameError)
```

I have tried deleting my vendor dir and 'rake clean'ing many times. [Here is a new blank project that I created that tries to use Parse as a cocoapod and gives me that error](https://github.com/pachun/Parse-Problem). I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look at that to see if it persists for you.

In the other scenario I added Parse as a vendored project. I also added a couple .dylib's and frameworks. [Here is another blank project I created to illustrate this scenario.](https://github.com/pachun/vendored-parse) When I try to run this version, I get the following compile time errors:

```
Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development
     Build vendor/Parse.framework
   Compile ./app/app_delegate.rb
    Create ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development/test.app
      Link ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development/test.app/test
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook", referenced from:
      +[PF_FBSession renewSystemAuthorization] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceFriends", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
      -[PF_FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_FBSettings.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFLocationManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPayment", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPaymentTransactionObserver.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_FBNativeDialogs.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
      +[PF_FBNativeDialogs composeViewControllerWithSession:handler:] in Parse(PF_FBNativeDialogs.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer...]
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:386:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/app.rb:72:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pachun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@motion/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/pachun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@motion/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => simulator => build:simulator
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If someone who's used parse could take a look at those and let me know if they get the same thing/what they think the problem is, I'd really appreciate it. This is holding me up. Thanks,

Pachun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no Parse CocoaPod.

Second, the problem with your Rakefile is that you didn't include all of the required libraries. Here's what works for me: https://gist.github.com/4367907

Comment: Thanks that worked! Which is awesome. Though, I am pretty sure there is a Parse cocoapod. Check it out. Go to cocoapods.org, type in Parse and click the search filter option "Called". It's a  couple down, but it's there. Version 1.1.10. If you click on it, it links you to Prase.com. Regardless, it doesn't work so it may as well not exist. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. If any Parsers come across this, care to weigh in?

Comment: I saw that CocoaPod as well and I don't think it worked for me either. Would be nice, especially if it's updated regularly.

Comment: Well the Parse iOS SDK is closed source, so wouldn't that make it impossible to be a CocoaPod? Also, you can't even download it from their site unless you are registered and logged in. Another reason why a Parse CocoaPod will probably never exist.

Comment: Thanks for the gist.  I wasted hours trying to sort this out, and I had it working fine for months until it broke suddenly.  Adding those frameworks in got me going again.

Comment: Happy to help. And feel free to try out the gem I wrote, ParseModel (github.com/adelevie/ParseModel), which adds some convenience methods on top of the Parse SDK.